# Nand flash chip ; I/O width of x8 and x16 bits?

Tags: ram, flash-memory, libcmtd

Can anyone explain me what is the difference between using a nand flash chip of x8 I/O width with x16 i/O width.

Answer (score 0):

For nand flash:

- x8 mode : it has a byte location within the page register
- x16 mode: it has a word location within the page register

at the interface:

- x16 device has total 16 IO pins(IO0~IO15) (tips: io8~io15 are only used in the SDR data interface)
- x8 device has total 8 IO pins(IO0~IO7)